# How do I automate converting PDF to HTML?

Tags: ms-word, extract

I work for a publisher and am trying to extract content from our fully laid out PDFs. I've tried pdftohtml, pdftotext, pdfminer, and other Python-based approaches to getting the content, as well as saving to Word, HTML, XML, etc. from the original Acrobat files.

I don't need just the text, I also need the text formatting. That's because, for example, I need all the blue text in the document.

When I save to HTML, Word, etc. from Acrobat, the resulting files contain screenshots of the pages, not the laid out text. When I extract text using different Python modules I get the text but lose the text formatting.

The only solution I've found is to manually copy and paste from the PDF into a word doc, then saving as HTML. I'm hoping to automate this.

Why does copying from Acrobat into Word achieve what I can't do by other means? Has anybody come across this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider another method. The software (https://pdfapi.codeplex.com/) can convert pdf files to html directly via MVS. If you are able to use the MVS, i think the software i mentioned above is useful for you to convert the text in pdf files to html that can keep the format perfectly. Of course, it's just a referral, you can have a try.